# Java Regular Expression Two Question marks (??)

Tags: regex

I know that /? means the / is optional. so "toys?" will match both toy and toys. My understanding is that if I make it lazy and use "toys??" I will match both toy and toys and always return toy. So, a quick test:

```
private final static Pattern TEST_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("toys??", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(String arg : args) {
        Matcher m = TEST_PATTERN.matcher(arg);
        System.out.print("Arg: " + arg);
        boolean b = false;
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.print(" {");
            for (int i=0; i<=m.groupCount(); ++i) {
                System.out.print("[" + m.group(i) + "]");
            }
            System.out.print("}");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Yep, it looks like it works as expected

```
java -cp .. regextest.RegExTest toy toys
Arg: toy {[toy]}
Arg: toys {[toy]}
```

Now, change the regular expression to "toys??2" and it still matches toys2 and toy2. In both cases, it returns the entire string without the s removed. Is there any functional difference between searching for "toys?2" and "toys??2".

The reason I am asking is because I found an example like the following:

```
private final static Pattern TEST_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("</??tag(\\s+?.*?)??>", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

and although I see no apparent reason for using ?? rather than ?, I thought that perhaps the original author (who is not known to me) might know something that I don't, I expect the later.

Comment: @remus: It is valid in Java

Comment: Why shouldn't it be valid? It's a lazy modification of `?`.

Comment: @nhahtdh bizarre, I've never heard of such a thing. Link?

Comment: @remus: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: @nhahtdh awesome, thanks. So it's syntactically valid, but appears to be identical to it's greedy counterpart.

Comment: @remus: It's not identical, it is lazy.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`??` is lazy while `?` is greedy.

Given `(pattern)??`, it will first test for empty string, then if the rest of the pattern can't match, it will test for `pattern`.

In contrast, `(pattern)?` will test for `pattern` first, then it will test for empty string on backtrack.

---

> Now, change the regular expression to "toys??2" and it still matches toys2 and toy2. In both cases, it returns the entire string without the s removed. Is there any functional difference between searching for "toys?2" and "toys??2".

The difference is in the order of searching:

- `"toys?2"` searches for `toys2`, then `toy2`
- `"toys??2"` searches for `toy2`, then `toys2`

But for the case of these 2 patterns, the result will be the same regardless of the input string, since the sequel `2` (after `s?` or `s??`) must be matched.

---

As for the pattern you found:

```
Pattern.compile("</??tag(\\s+?.*?)??>", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
```

Both `??` can be changed to `?` without affecting the result:

- `/` and `t` (in `tag`) are *mutually exclusive*. You either match one or the other.
- `>` and `\s` are also *mutually exclusive*. The at least 1 in `\s+?` is important to this conclusion: the result might be different otherwise.

This is probably micro-optimization from the author. He probably thinks that the open tag must be there, while the closing tag might be forgotten, and that open/close tags without attributes/random spaces appears more often than those with some.

By the way, the engine might run into some expensive backtracking attempt due to `\\s+?.*?` when the input has `<tag` followed by lots of spaces without `>` anywhere near.

Comment: Thanks.... So it does not affect the answer, just the efficiency based on the expected input.